# Gnuplottex: Pass latex command to gnuplot script

Tags: macros, expansion, external-files, gnuplottex

I want to access and plot the same data from different LaTeX documents (a paper and a beamer presentation) using [`gnuplottex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex). The data and the gnuplot script is stored at some individual position relative to the two documents. To re-use as much code as possible, I would like to define the relative path to the data in each document in a macro, here `\datapath`.

My question is: How can I pass the value of this command to the gnuplot script? I would basically like to use the following in my MWE:

```
plot \datapath'/data.csv' using 1:2 with lines
```

I did find [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116160/44634). However I was unable to modify it to my needs. Can someone help me, please?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
  miktex,    % 
  subfolder, % generated graphs in a ”gnuplottex” subfolder
  cleanup,   % Delete the .gnuplot files after conversion
]{gnuplottex}

\newcommand{\datapath}{./ZZZ}

\begin{document}

% This is the data file to be plotted from
\begin{filecontents*}{\datapath/data.csv}
Col1,Col2
0,0
1,1
\end{filecontents*}

% This is the gnuplot script I would like to use the value of \datapath in
\begin{filecontents*}{\datapath/script.gnuplot}
set key autotitle columnhead
set datafile separator "," # for csv-file
plot './ZZZ/data.csv' using 1:2 with lines
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\gnuplotloadfile[terminal=cairolatex]{\datapath/script.gnuplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me on Linux with pdflatex.

Comment: Sure, it works great, no question. But I want to be able to use `plot \datapath'/data.csv' using 1:2 with lines` instead of `plot './ZZZ/data.csv' using 1:2 with lines`. But how can I pass and expand the value of `\datapath` inside the gnuplot document or store the content of `\datapath` in a variable inside the gnuplot script as done in the post I linked to in my question?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/923955 I guess you need to do `\renewcommand{\gnuplotexe}{gnuplot -e "dirname=./ZZZ"}` and use `dirname` in the script file. I don't know about quoting, though, perhaps you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `\immediate\write` instead of `filecontents*`:

```
\newwrite\tempfile

\immediate\openout\tempfile=\datapath/script.gnuplot
\immediate\write\tempfile{set key autotitle columnhead; 
set datafile separator ","; 
plot '\datapath/data.csv' using 1:2 with lines}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
```

Comment: Thanks, but the data files and the gnuplot script exist as files at a defined location. `filecontents*` was only used here to provide a complete MWE.

Comment: I guess then I don't understand your question. How are you going to pass the location of the data if you don't write it to the script file?

Comment: That exactly is my question. In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115916/latex-variable-inside-gnuplot-code/116160#116160) the value of the line color is stored in a macro and expanded into a variable `s` inside the gnuplot script without writing it. So I guess it is possible. I just wasn't able to modify the approach to my problem. I always get the error that the files cannot be found.

Comment: This would require modifying the gnuplottex source code to read and replace a macro in the file.